# Ajax transfer data but not show success message

Tags: jquery, ajax, ajaxform

My Ajax sending data successfully but not showing s
success message .In console there is no error.

```
''''
<script type="text/javascript">
function user_register(){
    var num1=jQuery('#name').val();
    var num2=jQuery('#email').val();
    var num3=jQuery('#mobile').val();
    var num4=jQuery('#password').val();
    // user_register.preventDefault();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url:'registration.php',
        type:'post',
        data:'num1='+num1+'&num2='+num2+'&num3='+num3+'&num4='+num4,
        success:function(result){
            console.log("Success");
            alert(result);
        }
    })

}
```

Comment: what is the http status code?

Answer (score 0):

Success will only trigger's when server responds 'Successful responses'.
Note what is the Status code your getting from Server, also try to Enable error block.

Refer : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

```
.error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
}
```

Comment: thanks to you for this helpful information, but I am working on localhost.

Comment: @RoshniMahk even Localhost also u r requesting endpoint : "registration.php". That has to return some  'Successful responses'.

Comment: @RoshniMahk even Localhost also your requesting endpoint : "registration.php". Check the Header that your request is landing properly also inside "Registration.php" file after all the Logic done that has to return some  'Successful responses'.